# Box-Cox, Exogenous Variables and Time Series Models

Tags: time-series, data-transformation

I am building time series models using SARIMAX from Statsmodels (Python).

The independent variables in my models include 3 to 5 exogenous variables that are other than the target variable I am trying to predict.

I am finding that there is some value in using Box-Cox to transform my target (i.e. independent) variable.

In these cases, should I also be applying the same Box-Cox transformation to my exogenous variables?

(I believe the answer is no.)

Comment: Would you be willing to transform some of the variables but not all of them?  That is tantamount to using a different transformation (no transformation is the Box-Cox transformation of power $1$).

Comment: Yes - transforming only some of my exogenous variables would be an option.

Comment: Then you have provided the answer.

Comment: Ok, so I think I am hearing the following advice: (1) explore box-cox transforms for each of my exogenous variables, (2) each such transform might use a different lambda value.  Am I getting that right?  If yes, how would I describe what the benefit of these transforms might be?

Comment: That's a broad question.  I have provided some answers at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/4833/919 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/35717/919.  Also see some of the discussion at the end of https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/259223/919.  Here's an entire thread on understanding Box-Cox transformations: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/467494.