# Transformed Data with Boxcox and negative Lambda

Tags: data-transformation, back-transformation

unfortunately I'm a statistics beginner. I am trying to transform my data. Here, according to Boxcox, a transformation with negative lambda has resulted ( L =-0.25).

But If I now run a T-tests with the transformed data, the results are exactly the other way around than expected --> that makes sense, because of the minus in the variable --> higher values are lower afterwards. But does anyone have an idea how I can interpret or transform the results, to get it right?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "other way around than expected"?  There is, after all, no reason to suppose that the averages of the $-1/4$ powers of data will have any determinate relationship to the averages of the original data.  What, then, do you mean by "get it right"??

Comment: Data was previously transformed with L=-0.25. Consequently, a value such as 400 --> 0.224; a value such as 200 -->0.265. I want to compare these two. Thus, the second value is larger in the transformed form, although it was smaller before. If I now do a T-test of the transformed data it shows me a significant difference, but in the opposite way. Consequently, I cannot interpret the result directly and would have to transform it back or I don't know (?) Or did I do something wrong?

Comment: You aren't describing a Box-Cox transformation.  Those are constructed to preserve the order of the data.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/467525/919 for instance.  (The plots near the end include graphs of the $\lambda=-1/2$ transform, which will behave much like $\lambda=-1/4.$) Regardless, a t-test (or any test) comparing the means of the transformed data is not equivalent to a comparison of the means of the untransformed data.  Thus, you have to decide what test you really need to perform.

Comment: What do you mean with I not describe a BoxCox-Transformation? Pages told me, that I can use a L=-0,25. Also the BoxCox-Powertransformation told me to use L=-0,25