# Why does my data look the same after log, root, Box-Cox transformations?

Tags: forecasting, data-transformation, stationarity

I have to forecast the amount of cars sales for the next 12 months. The data I have gathered are from 2013-2021 (108 months). This is what the plot of my data looks like using  Rstudio and its function plot.ts():
[image: raw data]

We can see the mean and the variance are not constant - so I tried the log, root and Box-Cox transformations and all the graphs I got still remain the same (except, of course, the y-axis). They are all shaped identically and therefore none of my graphs is stationary. Here are what my log and root transformation plots look like:

[image: log transformation]

[image: root transformation]

What can explain this issue? I tried to look it up online and but couldn't find anything.

Comment: The relative range of your values is so small that it makes little difference which of those transformations you take: they are *all* designed not to change data that have only a little variation.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/467525/919 for details.  BTW, it is not at all evident that "mean and variance [are] not constant." Sure, the mean appears to increase a little over time, but what leads you to believe the variance is not constant?

Comment: @whuber I was asked to gather max 112 observations and to do a data transformation if the variance appears not to be constant - towards the 70th month, it seemed to me that the variance starts to increase...

Comment: It's difficult to determine that just from looking at the plot of data.  Consider first smoothing the data and examining a plot of the residuals: that will give you a clearer sense of whether the variance changes and how.  Yes, there is some indication of more variability at later dates, but it isn't necessarily a change in variance: there appear to be some *structural breaks* around times 72 and 84 that might be better handled as such.  No transformation is going to help you deal with those.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/74594/919 for a worked example.