# Mean of bootstrapped medians

Tags: mean, bootstrap, median, robust

I have a large set (10^6) of very small sets (5-10 entries) of numbers. For each of them, I want to compute a sensible average measure. An example might be this:

$$
x = [-2, 5, -1, 3, 100]
$$

Because of the nature of the data, I know that the 100 is not an outlier, but it should also not be taken too seriously (hard to explain better without going into boring details). Hence, I want use use neither the median (which loses too much information), nor the arithmetic mean (which gives too much weight to the 100). Using the intercept of a robust regression $x$ ~ $1$ also effectively treats the 100 as an outlier.

So, I came up with the following approach:

1. For a set with $n$ numbers ($n=5$ in the above example), select with replacement $n$ samples.
2. Compute the median of these $n$ samples.
3. Repeat steps 1 and 2 $m>>1$ times, and compute the mean of the $m$ medians.

For a set with $n$ numbers, there are $n^n$ possibilities for sampling with replacement, so if $n$ is small, this can also be done deterministically by exhausting all possibilities.

The results I obtained ($7.8096$ for the above example) correspond extremely well to what I would intuitively consider a good average measure, given what I know about the data.

I'm surprised I've never heard about this measure, given how natural it feels for computing a robust average that incorporates all data entries. Does anyone know more about it and can point me to relevant literature? Or more generally to information about the distribution of bootstrapped medians of finite sets of numbers?

Comment: "not be taken too seriously" and "correspond extremely well" are purely subjective, could you formalize what exactly you want to achieve? There are infinitely many completely arbitrary mathematical functions that would return a nice-looking number between -2 and 100.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I hear what you're saying, but feel that it won't be helpful to go into the details of the data. I'm mostly just interested in what statistical properties this mean of medians number (that I've never heard about) has. For example, is there perhaps an approximation I can compute more quickly that converges to the median-mean for large n and m? ...

Comment: It sounds like what you want is the mean of (n+1)/2 order statistics of distribution for odd n and the average of the mean of n/2 and n/2 + 1 th statistics of distribution for even n. Not sure what it serves but there are ways to construct the PDF of the median you want as long as you have the underlying distribution in mind.

Comment: The "mean of the m medians" is a weighted average of order statistics.  Although you can estimate this with a bootstrap, that's incredibly inefficient, because you can work out the coefficients merely from the original sample size.  Linear combinations of order statistics have been used in many applications, especially for robust estimation of population properties.

Comment: @whuber, could you share a reference explaining how I can compute the number in question more efficiently?

Comment: As I explain at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/160148/919 (and elsewhere here on CV), the Binomial distribution tells you everything you need to know about the distribution of medians of subsamples of a dataset.

Comment: Thank you @whuber. I've had a look but sadly lack the background to translate your responses to my particular problem. Could you describe how I can use the binomial distribution to compute the mean of medians more efficiently, and post this as an Answer?

Comment: this sounds like a distribution of a sample quantile. the median of any given set is a sample 50% quantile. so you're bootstrapping this distribution to obtain its mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In principle we will have to handle ties in the data, so let's adopt a convenient notation.  Let the data have values $x_1\lt x_2 \lt \cdots \lt x_d$ where the value $x_k$ appears with multiplicity $\nu_k \ge 1.$ Write $n_k = \nu_1 + \nu_2 + \cdots + \nu_k$ for the partial sums, so that $n = \nu_d$ is the dataset size.

You describe a random variable created by sampling $m = n$ values $X_1,X_2,\ldots, X_m$ from these data (with replacement) and computing their $q = 1/2$ quantile $X.$  Given any index $k,$ what is the chance that $x_k$ is this quantile?

Let's say that a "success" at step $i$ is that $X_i \le x_k.$  This event has probability $n_k/n.$  Because $X \le x_k$ exactly when there have been $qm$  or more successes when drawing the sample of size $m,$

$$\Pr(X \le x_k) = S\left(qm; m, n_k/n\right)$$

where $S$ is the cumulative Binomial survival function (computable as an incomplete Gamma integral or, for small $m,$ directly using Binomial coefficients).  Abbreviating the right hand side as $p_k,$ we obtain $\Pr(X = x_k) = p_k - p_{k-1}$ and the expectation is

$$E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^k x_k\left(p_k - p_{k-1}\right).$$

This is (explicitly) a linear combination of the order statistics of the original $n$ data values $y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_n$ where the coefficient of $y_i$ is $(p_k-p_{k-1})/\nu_k$ when $y_i = x_k.$  The highest weights tend to be concentrated near the $q$ quantile of the data.

**To illustrate,** on the left is a bar chart of $n=24$ data showing $(x_k, \nu_k).$  In the middle is a plot of the distribution $(x_k, p_k - p_{k-1})$ for $q = 30\%.$  This shows how the weights are concentrated around a few data values.  At the right is a histogram of the $30^\text{th}$ percentiles of a thousand independent bootstrap samples (using the default `quantile` calculation in `R`).  The difference between the average of these thousand quantiles and the computed expectation is insignificant ($Z = -0.005$).

[image]

In an application with no ties likely and predictable dataset sizes $n$ (such as the five to ten in the question) you can precompute the $p_k$ for each possible $n,$ making the calculation extremely efficient.  If there aren't too many ties in any case you wouldn't be wrong to just sort the data and use the precomputed $p_k.$

This `R` code generated the figures.

```R
#
# Make some data.
#
set.seed(17)
nu <- table(y <- round(rnorm(24, -2, 3)))
#
# Preprocessing.
#
x <- as.numeric(names(nu))
n <- cumsum(nu)
n. <- n[length(n)]
#
# Specify the subsampling.
#
m <- n.
q <- 3/10
#
# Compute the expectation of X.
#
dp <- diff(c(0, pbinom(q * m, m, n/n., lower.tail = FALSE)))
dpm <- rev(diff(c(0, pbinom((1-q) * m, m, n/n., lower.tail = FALSE))))
dp <- (dp + dpm) / 2 # Assures agreement between `pbinom` and `quantile` conventions
xq.hat <- sum(x * dp)
#
# Confirm with a simulation.
#
n.sim <- 1e3
z <- replicate(n.sim, quantile(sample(y, m, replace = TRUE), q))
#
# Test the difference between the mean simulated value and the computation.
#
delta <- mean(z) - xq.hat
se <- sd(y) / sqrt(length(y))
Z <- delta / se
(signif(c(Delta = delta, SE = se, Z = Z), 2))
#
# Show what happened in plots.
#
par(mfrow = c(1,3))
plot(x, nu, type = "h", lwd = 5, main = "Original Data", 
     ylab = expression(nu), ylim = c(0, max(nu)))
plot(x, dp, type = "b", lwd = 2, xlab = "x", ylab = "Probability", 
     main = "Distribution of X", pch = 21)
hist(z, main = paste0("Simulated ", q, " Quantiles"), xlab = "X",
     xlim = range(x))
abline(v = xq.hat, lwd = 2, col = "Red")
par(mfrow = c(1,1))
```

Comment: That's fantastic and exactly what I needed - thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: +1. I don't fully understand why it is $\nu_k >1$ and not $\nu_k \geq 1$?

Comment: @COOLSerdash Just a typo -- thanks for pointing that out.  The important thing was to stipulate the multiplicities are nonzero (although that really won't affect the arithmetic in the end).

Comment: @whuber: I believe there is a mistake in your code if the number of elements is even. For example, replacing your `round(rnorm(24, -2, 3))` with `c(-1,1)` and using `q=0.5` produces `xq.hat = 0.5` instead of the correct `0.0`. The relative error decreases as the number of elements in the set becomes large, but given that I work with small sets (many of which have even numbers of elements), this is an issue for me.

Comment: There will inevitably be issues with how one defines a quantile in such cases: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/603002/919 for a discussion.  To implement a symmetric quantile, simply use this code to compute its expectation of the $q$ quantile of the data $x$ and then again to compute its expectation of the $1-q$ quantile using the *reversed* version of those data.  Average the two results.  I have modified the code to implement this approach.